# Issue with running SH file

Tags: command-line, bash, permission, script

I am trying to run the file `run.sh` with the command `sh run.sh`
However, I get the error of permission being denied whether I use sudo or not.

```
shloakagrawal@shloaks-air EaglerGradle-1.0 % sudo sh run.sh
run.sh: line 3: ./bin/EaglerGradle: Permission denied
shloakagrawal@shloaks-air EaglerGradle-1.0 % sh run.sh
run.sh: line 3: ./bin/EaglerGradle: Permission denied
```

Please ask for any other information

Comment: Without knowing what the script is actually doing, we can only guess.

Comment: What is the output of `head -10 run.sh`, what of `ls -l .bin/EagerGradle`?

Answer (score 1):

You can only execute a file if it has the execute permission. To give `bin/EagerGradle` the execute permission, run

```
chmod +x bin/EaglerGradle
```

You may want to run `chmod +x run.sh` as well so that you can run `./run.sh` or `/some/path/to/run.sh` without having to explicitly invoke `sh`.

However, note that this may be a symptom of a bigger problem. Running the chmod command above won't cause any harm, but it might not make EaglerGradle actually work. You might need to re-do the installation correctly.